# In visual studio 2017, is there a way to compile a custom extension that uses an external tool, while debugging a program?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I would like to compile a .shader file while debugging a program. VS 2017 asks me to stop debugging the program in order to compile.

I've setup a .Targets and .props to compile all *.shader files in the solution after the regular build. The exe does not get affected by the *.shader builds in any way.

Is there a flag in the .targets file that says “enablecompilewhiledebug”? I think that would be useful in cases where the target doesnt affect the exe built. I expect that while debugging a program, if i open up any .shader file, I should be able to compile it using the external tool based on how its setup in the .targets file, without asking me to stop debugging. I'd like to do this without leaving the current solution (i.e. use another solution or external tool).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the answer provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, there has no such reference in target can meet your needs. And when in debugging mode, the debug.exe will call the source code and occupy the output ones(.exe or .dll) to find bugs. At that point, the compile progress can’t cover the old output files(.exe or .dll) with new ones using the source files. So in visual studio for now, we have no valid way to enable compile when debugging. 
Thanks for your understanding.